# Is it possible to include buttons (that change motion.conf file) in the same page as camera feed is streaming to?

Tags: video, streaming-video

I recently purchased a Raspberry Pi 3 (with camera module) and have successfully gotten it to stream with its IP address.

So, I was just wondering:  Is it possible (and if so, how?) to integrate buttons on the same web page as the video stream?  Specifically, buttons that are able to change things like the video feed's size (height/width), rotating it, etc.  (Basically the things in the motion.conf file.)

Any help is appreciated.